# RegEx: Not only digits in email

Tags: regex

How can I improve my My RegEx in order to forbid input only digits in my email.

**My RegEx:**

```
^([a-z0-9а-я_.-]{4,20})@([a-zа-я_]{2,5})\\.([a-zа-я]{2,5})(\\.[a-zа-я]{2,5})?$
```

**Invalid:**

```
1111@gmail.com
```

**Valid:**

```
check@gmail.com
```

Comment: don't understand the question.  You want only digits?  Give us example of valid email.  (e.g. @ is not a digit)

Comment: 1111@gmail.com //invalid

Comment: check@gmail.com //valid

Comment: Negative lookahead is the answer (see below), but *note that "digits-only emails" are perfectly valid,* and your current regex is too restrictive already. 
E.g. it's perfectly valid to have only one char before "@", the domain name part may have digits, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may add `(?![0-9]+@)` after `^` in your regex:

```
^(?![0-9]+@)([a-z0-9а-я_.-]{4,20})@([a-zа-я_]{2,5})\\.([a-zа-я]{2,5})(\\.[a-zа-я]{2,5})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The negative lookahead will fail all cases where you have 1 or more digits followed with `@` at the start of the string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FejeUZ/1).

Comment: I used it in my custom use case and it seems to work.

Thank you